# XML to array, xml2ary bug

Tags: php, xml

I am using this function  http://mysrc.blogspot.it/2007/02/php-xml-to-array-and-backwards.html 
to parse an XML to an Array. Very great function. But the strange thing is that
if I have the following 2 xml files:

```
<response>
<company prop1=1>
</company>
<company prop1=2>
</company>
</response>

<response>
<company prop1=1>
</company>
</response>
```

I got different result. For the first case, I got an array of two elements:

```
Array(
  int(0) => _a => Array(...)
  int(1) => _a => Array(...)
)
```

but for the second case I got

```
  Array (
    _a => Array(...)
  )
```

which is not an array with indexes as the first case. This complicates parsing.
Does anybody have any idea how to modify the code?
Regards.

Comment: Can you add the 2nd XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you do something like

```
$result = xml2ary($xml);
```

Try adding this line after your call to xml2ary():

```
$result = is_int(reset(array_keys($result))) ? $result : array($result);
```

This checks if the first key of the result array is an integer (which means that the `xml2ary` function returned multiple results. If not, it automatically wraps the `$result` variable in an array(), so that you have the same response format even when only one XML item is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PHP `simplexml` class:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

It's the best way to parse XML with PHP